# Java 2-D array returning NULL

Tags: java, arrays, null, return

I am working to create a "basic" UI connect4 game. I am having trouble figuring out why when I call to print the "board", I am getting null, in return. Have I not initialize the array? If so, how do I do so? ~Thanks

My constructor...

```
public class Connect4{ 
    private String game[][];
    public Conncet4(String game[][]){
         this.game = game;
    }
```

with one of my methods...

```
public void dropChipX(int colm){    
    for(int i = 0; i<game.length;i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<game[0].length;j++) {
            if( j%2 == 0 )
                game[game.length-1][col] = "|";
            else
                game[i][j] = " ";
        }
    }

    if(game[game.length-1][colm] == " ")
        game[game.length-1][colm] = "X";
    else
        game[(game.length-1)-count][col] = "X";
    count++;

}
```

I also have a toString to print out the array

```
public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<game.length;i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<game[0].length;j++)
            result = (game[i][j]);
        result += "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

The thing I am having trouble with is that when I do run my main, its returning null

```
public class Connect4TextConsole {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fun[][] = new String[6][15];
    Connect4 connect = new Connect4(fun);

    connect.dropChipX(3);
    System.out.print(connect);
    connect.dropChipY(2);
    System.out.print(connect);
}
```

}

Comment: There are so many errors in your code. Starting with typos, after that you're comparing `String`s with `==` instead of `compare`, then, you haven't declare some of the variables (e.g. `count`... My advice to you is to debug your code. Debugging is essential skill every programmer **must** have. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to reconsider this code:

```
public class Connect4{ 
    private String game[][];
    public Conncet4(String game[][]){
         this.game = game;
    }
}
```

You should make a defensive copy of that 2D array inside the constructor.

Any code that gave you the reference to the game 2D array that's passed to the constructor can modify that mutable reference.  Your private designation means nothing.

Comment: Very good tip! But OP's code has too many errors, both logical and syntactical...

Comment: Agreed. I’m addressing something besides his question.